# The source for the proof of the uniformization theorem in Gamelin's book

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

The book on Complex Analysis by Gamelin has the singular feature that it has a more-or-less complete proof of the Uniformization theorem for Riemann surfaces (*countable topology not assumed!*) despite being an undergraduate textbook. I am currently lecturing on the proof to graduate students. It seems to me that, modulo some hand-waving here-and -there, the proof given here is both the shortest and most transparent especially the proof of the second-countability of Riemann surfaces.

I have been asked by the students about the original source of the proof. I know that Marshall's book has a proof that is similar in spirit but that is obviously not the source. Does anybody know a source for the proof?

Answer (score 2):

The proof in Don Marshall's book is based off of some notes he wrote. The version as of 2011 can be found on his webpage as the third preprint:
[https://sites.math.washington.edu//~marshall/preprints/preprints.html](https://sites.math.washington.edu//%7Emarshall/preprints/preprints.html)

I had a hunch that Marshall's notes were much older than his new (and wonderful) textbook, and indeed he comments on his webpage that Gamelin's proof is based off of his original notes. This makes sense, since both make use of a dipole Green's function, and in the preprint Marshall states this is a novel part of his approach.

As for what source motivated Marshall's proof? I do not know. But I do know the uniformization theorem has quite the rich history and many authors have contributed important ideas to its proof(s), see the following survey [http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math401.F09/GrayRMT.pdf](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math401.F09/GrayRMT.pdf)